# Rspec: how do I test for a redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I've got some routes that look like this:

```
constraints ClientCodeConstraint.new do
  get 'share/:client_code', to: redirect('/%{client_code}')
  get 'share/:client_code/:id', to: redirect('/%{client_code}/%{id}')
  get ':client_code', to: 'share#index', as: :shares
  get ':client_code/:id', to: 'share#show', as: :share
  get ':client_code/:document_id/more/:component_id', to: 'share#more', as: :more
end
```

My constraint looks like this:

```
class ClientCodeConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    users.each do |user|
      return true if request.path_parameters[:client_code] == user.client_code
    end
  end

  def users
    @users ||= User.all
  end
end
```

I've got tests like this but I'm having no luck:

```
context 'not logged in' do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  let!(:document) { create(:document) }

  specify 'renders the :index view' do
    get :index
    expect(response.code).to eq '302'
    expect(response).to redirect_to("/#{assigns(:user).client_code}")
  end

  specify 'renders the :show view' do
    get :show
    expect(response).to redirect_to("/#{assigns(:user).client_code}/#{assigns(:document).id}")
  end
end
```

How do I test with Rspec these redirects? I just get a bunch of these errors:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"share"}
```

And the controller and routes of course exist.

**UPDATE**

Relevant `rake routes` output is here:

```
GET    /share/:client_code(.:format)                           :controller#:action
GET    /share/:client_code/:id(.:format)                       :controller#:action
shares GET    /:client_code(.:format)                                 share#index
share GET    /:client_code/:id(.:format)                             share#show
more GET    /:client_code/:document_id/more/:component_id(.:format) share#more
```

The tests pass like this:

```
specify 'renders the :index view' do
  get :index, client_code: user.client_code
  expect(response.status).to eq(200)
end
```

That feels though like I'm testing only that the response is correct. I want to test more thoroughly, i.e., it doesn't render an error message, etc.

Comment: attach `rake routes` output

Comment: Looks like your `assigns(:user).client_code` is returning nil. Your route is `/share/:client_code`, and it looks like you're trying to generate a route for share with a nil :client_code.

Comment: Also, a response.status of 200 would specifically tell you that your code is not succeeding, because a redirect status code is 302